# how to put the settings functionality for Push Notification on/off inside the app in ios

Tags: ios, push-notification, application-settings

I made push notification for iOS according to my app requirement. If I want to manually turn off the push notifications, I will go to Settings and click the Notification off then Notifications are off.

But I want to implement notifications settings functionality *inside* the app. This means I'm going to my app menu and click the settings button and off the notifications. Then push notifications should get turned off. Is it possible to put the push notifications settings functionality inside the app for notifications are on/off?

Comment: @Immi, I rolled back your changes; decorating random keywords as code to "highlight them" is not good editing practice.

Comment: @Chris i was reading your post. it was so collapsed and was not able to understand it. i just marked it boldly.

Comment: Sorry! You can ONLY check whether Push Notifications are enable/disable through your app but CAN'T toggle for on/off as that alert view asking for push notifications can only view once.

Comment: @NSS:You can enable and disable notification but make sure you have accepted  at first time when it asking for permission. check **maulik's** answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can you use `UISwitch` control for on/off OR you can also use separate `UIButton` for on/off.

You just need to unregister for remoteNotification by : ( Off )

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];`

When you want to register again then  ( On )

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(
UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

Answer (score 2):

To unregister for remoteNotification you can use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]unregisterForRemoteNotifications];
```

When you again want to register then follow standard approach.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
(UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability|
UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

But you can't change in settings programatically.